# How to merge two data.table by different column names?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I have two data.table **X** and **Y**.

columns in **X**: `area, id, value`
columns in **Y**: `ID, price, sales`

Create the two data.tables:

```
X = data.table(area=c('US', 'UK', 'EU'),
               id=c('c001', 'c002', 'c003'),
               value=c(100, 200, 300)
              )

Y = data.table(ID=c('c001', 'c002', 'c003'),
               price=c(500, 200, 400),
               sales=c(20, 30, 15)
              )
```

And I set keys for **X** and **Y**:

```
setkey(X, id)
setkey(Y, ID)
```

Now I try to join **X** and **Y** by `id` in **X** and `ID` in **Y**:

```
merge(X, Y)
merge(X, Y, by=c('id', 'ID'))
merge(X, Y, by.x='id', by.y='ID')
```

All raised error saying that column names in the `by` argument invalid.

I referred to the manual of data.table and found the `merge` function not supporting `by.x` and `by.y` arguments.

How could I join two data.tables by different column names **without changing the column names**?

**Append**:
I managed to join the two tables by `X[Y]`, but why `merge` function fails in data.table?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047253/merging-tables-with-different-column-names or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612859/joining-tables-based-on-different-column-names

Comment: @akrun Thank you. I did checked the two posts. I managed to join **X** and **Y** by `X[Y]`, but I still could not accomplish it by using `merge` function. I am quite confused about why `merge` fails in data.table.

Comment: by.x and by.y are not yet implemented for data.tables. A FR is filed. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069796/merging-data-tables-based-on-columns-names

Comment: the `by` arguments are available in `data.table v1.9.6` on CRAN as of Sep 2015. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34756170/4002530) for use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### OUTDATED

---

Use this operation:

```
X[Y]
#    area   id value price sales
# 1:   US c001   100   500    20
# 2:   UK c002   200   200    30
# 3:   EU c003   300   400    15
```

or this operation:

```
Y[X]
#      ID price sales area value
# 1: c001   500    20   US   100
# 2: c002   200    30   UK   200
# 3: c003   400    15   EU   300
```

**Edit** after you edited your question, I read Section 1.12 of the [FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf): "What is the didifference between X[Y] and merge(X,Y)?", which led me to checkout `?merge` and I discovered there are two different merge functions depending upon which package you are using. The default is `merge.data.frame` but data.table uses `merge.data.table`. Compare

```
merge(X, Y, by.x = "id", by.y = "ID") # which is merge.data.table
# Error in merge.data.table(X, Y, by.x = "id", by.y = "ID") : 
# A non-empty vector of column names for `by` is required.
```

with

```
merge.data.frame(X, Y, by.x = "id", by.y = "ID")
#     id area value price sales
# 1 c001   US   100   500    20
# 2 c002   UK   200   200    30
# 3 c003   EU   300   400    15
```

**Edit for completeness** based upon a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069796/merging-data-tables-based-on-columns-names) by @Michael Bernsteiner, it looks like the `data.table` team is planning on implementing `by.x` and `by.y` into the `merge.data.table` function, but hasn't done so yet.

Answer (score 46):

As of `data.table` version 1.9.6 (on CRAN on sep 2015) you can specify the `by.x` and `by.y` arguments in `data.table::merge`

```
merge(x=X, y=Y, by.x="id", by.y="ID")[]
#     id area value price sales
#1: c001   US   100   500    20
#2: c002   UK   200   200    30
#3: c003   EU   300   400    15
```

However, in data.table 1.9.6 you can **also** specfy the `on` argument in the `X[Y]` notation

> X[Y] syntax can now join without having to set keys by using the new on argument. For example: DT1[DT2, on=c(x = "y")] would join column "y" of DT2 with "x" of DT1. DT1[DT2, on="y"] would join column "y" of both data.tables.

```
X[Y, on=c(id = "ID")]
#   area   id value price sales
#1:   US c001   100   500    20
#2:   UK c002   200   200    30
#3:   EU c003   300   400    15
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645997/4002530) by the `data.table` author has more details

Comment: Is it better to use the first merthod or the second one?

Comment: @skan - I'm not sure I can say which is 'better'. Just be aware that `data.table::merge` sets `sort = TRUE` by default, which will set a key on the resulting data. This is something to look out for if you're not using keys

Answer (score 5):

Merge fails when you use `by.x` and `by.y` with `data.table`. Taking your data:

```
> merge(X,Y, by.x='id', by.y='ID')
Error in merge.data.table(X, Y, by.x = "id", by.y = "ID")
```

You can use `data.table` with merge , but you need to use `by` argument for joining (so rename the columns to have the same `colnames`)

```
Y = setNames(Y,c('id','price','sales'))
```

This will still not work:

```
merge(X,Y, by.x='id', by.y='id')
Error in merge.data.table(X, Y, by.x = "id", by.y = "id") :
```

But this will work:

```
> merge(X,Y, by='id')
#     id area value price sales
#1: c001   US   100   500    20
#2: c002   UK   200   200    30
#3: c003   EU   300   400    15
```

Alternatively, you would need to convert `data.table` to `data.frame` in order to use `merge` with `by.x` and `by.y` arguments:

```
merge(data.frame(X), data.frame(Y), by.x='id', by.y='ID')
```

Comment: You could also do `library(dplyr); XY <- setDT(left_join(tbl_df(X), tbl_df(Y), by = c("id" = "ID")))`

Comment: Given the updates to `data.table` this answer is no longer correct

Answer (score 2):

You can also merge using multiple columns having different names. see example below

```
# create data frame authors
authors <- data.frame(
FirstName=c("Lorne", "Loren", "Robin",
              "Robin", "Billy"),
LastName=c("Green", "Jaye", "Green",
             "Howe", "Jaye"),
Age=c(82, 40, 45, 2, 40),
Income=c(1200000, 40000, 25000, 0, 27500),
Home=c("California", "Washington", "Washington",
    "Alberta", "Washington"))

# create data frame books Note First name in authors is same as AuthorFirstname same thing with lastname.
books <- data.frame(
        AuthorFirstName=c("Lorne", "Loren", "Loren",
            "Loren", "Robin", "Rich"),
        AuthorLastName=c("Green", "Jaye", "Jaye", "Jaye",
            "Green", "Calaway"),
        Book=c("Bonanza", "Midwifery", "Gardening",
        "Perennials", "Who_dun_it?", "Support"))

merge(authors, books, by.x=c("FirstName", "LastName"),
      by.y=c("AuthorFirstName", "AuthorLastName"),
      all.x=TRUE)
```