# X[Y] join syntax with the 'on' argument

Tags: r, data.table

This question is a follow-up from a previous one:

[left outer join with data.table with different names for key variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644707/left-outer-join-with-data-table-with-different-names-for-key-variables)

I have now tried to use the "on" argument in the manner suggested by Matt Dowle. I am puzzled that it does not work. I wonder if this currently works only with version 1.9.7 of data.table.

```
packageVersion('data.table')
# [1] ‘1.9.6’

DT1 = data.table(x1 = c("b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b"), 
                 x2a = as.character(1:6), m1 = seq(10, 60, by = 10))
DT1
#    x1 x2a m1
# 1:  b   1 10
# 2:  c   2 20
# 3:  a   3 30
# 4:  b   4 40
# 5:  a   5 50
# 6:  b   6 60

DT2 = data.table(x1 = c("b", "d", "c", "b" ,"a", "a"),
                 x2b = c(1, 4, 7, 6, " ", " ") ,m2 = 5:10)
DT2
#    x1 x2b m2
# 1:  b   1  5
# 2:  d   4  6
# 3:  c   7  7
# 4:  b   6  8
# 5:  a      9
# 6:  a     10

#### merge command works fine
rtL <- merge(DT1, DT2, by.x = c('x1', 'x2a'),
             by.y = c('x1', 'x2b'), all.x = TRUE)
rtL
#    x1 x2a m1 m2
# 1:  a   3 30 NA
# 2:  a   5 50 NA
# 3:  b   1 10  5
# 4:  b   4 40 NA
# 5:  b   6 60  8
# 6:  c   2 20 NA   

#### Join with the X[Y] syntax with the 'on' argument
rtL2 <- DT2[DT1, on = c('x1', x2a = 'x2b')]
```

> Error in `forderv(x, by = rightcols)` : 
>         `by` value -2147483648 out of range [1,3]

What is wrong here? Does this require version 1.9.7?

```
##### Another attempt with the x1 variable in quotes
rtL3 <- DT2[DT1, on = c("x1", "x2a" = "x2b")]
```

> Error in `forderv(x, by = rightcols)` : 
>         `by` value -2147483648 out of range [1,3]

It seems to me that the `rtL2` version is more correct.

How do I interpret the error message? And what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: ..might be due to missing `x2b` in `DT2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, this is an issue with 1.9.6 that has since been fixed in the development version.

The problem (in addition to getting the order switched) is that you don't name the the counterpart to `x1` in `DT2`, see [GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table):

> 6. When joining with `on=`, `X[Y, on=c(A="A", b="c")]` can be now specified as `X[Y, on=c("A", b="c")]`, fully closes [#1375](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1375).

As for 1.9.6, the following works:

```
packageVersion('data.table')
# [1] ‘1.9.6’
DT1[DT2, on = c(x1 = "x1", x2a = "x2b")]
#    x1 x2a m1 m2
# 1:  b   1 10  5
# 2:  d   4 NA  6
# 3:  c   7 NA  7
# 4:  b   6 60  8
# 5:  a     NA  9
# 6:  a     NA 10
```